# php 5.2 no cache header

Tags: php, internet-explorer, caching

I dont want to save the pdf file in temp file as the file content didn't update when the temp file is updated , so i tried to use "no cache" as follow(I cleared the file before I use this function)

```
<?php
// Expires in the past
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT");
// Always modified
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
// HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
// HTTP/1.0
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

However,  the pdf file is stil saved in the temp file, the content of the pdf didn't update.
I am using php 5.2 and use IE Browser. Any problem with this code or any other method for example clear the cache everytime when i visit the webpage.

I put it on the top of the download file page

```
<?php
// Expires in the past
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT");
// Always modified
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
// HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
// HTTP/1.0
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
<?php  // $Id: view.php,v 1.61 2007/01/27 19:14:23 skodak Exp $

require_once("../../config.php");
require_once("lib.php");

$id = optional_param('id', 0, PARAM_INT);    // Course Module ID
$r  = optional_param('r', 0, PARAM_INT);  // Resource
.................................................
...............................................
.............................
?>
```

Comment: The code seems fine to me.. how do you include your PDF file?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your PHP is being run at all?

Try putting in `echo "foo"; exit()` at the top of this code and see if you can still download the PDF file - if you can, then your code is not being run, and your cache limiting wont be working.

Also, if you are using a Proxy server then that may be caching the file without your knowledge, try renaming the file and downloading it from the old location - if it still works then your server is probably not the problem.

Comment: the above code should place in the export function php file or place it in the page which provide the download path